# How can I learn UX design in my spare time?

Tags: user-behavior

I want to understand what makes web-based, user-facing products tick and how they could be more engaging. In particular, I'm interested in products that depend on users to generate and verify knowledge (such as Wikipedia). I am interested in optimizing both the micro (colours, panels, animations) and macro layout (site navigation, emotional feedback) for this.
I'm also fascinated (and unfamiliar) with data visualization, but that's probably not related.

I have a strong background in CS (Bachelor's degree; SWE at Google). I plan on doing this in my spare time and I would like a structured, academic, hands-on approach to keep me engaged. I think that (iterative) processes have a greater impact than facts in the long term.

Is https://www.coursera.org/specializations/interaction-design an excellent resource?
What are some communities and tools that you find useful? Such as must-read books, blogs, internet communities and sites to build and showcase projects (github for designers?).

All this probably looks like a rambling and incoherent wall of text. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm not a UX expert but I like reading the most popular questions here. Question and answers are very interesting and you can learn a lot very quickly.... Go to "Questions" and select "Votes" or "Frequent" to so the most exciting questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

There's too many elements and components in your question to be able to answer fully, so I'll just address the one about learning UX in your spare time.

**Short answer:**

Talk to people, listen to people, observe people whenever you get a chance, and find out what it is that makes them 'tick' (both in a good and bad way).

**Long answer:**

I think transitioning to UX doesn't necessarily require any new skills or knowledge, but rather a shift in the way you think about things. And by that I mean you have to train yourself to think and view the world not through your own eyes, but the eyes of someone else, particularly people who may have very little in common with you. If you go ask the best UX designers what they think is the most important attribute or quality, they will hopefully say that it is EMPATHY.

How do you build on your ability to be empathetic? I actually find the best way is to experience as many different things as possible, so that you can continually challenge your perception of things and refine your thinking so it becomes more objective and critical in understanding the way things work. I imagine that it might be something like an engineer crossed with a psychologist almost.

Of course, you can sign up to as many courses and training as you like, but that would mostly teach you about the knowledge and skills you need, not the thinking that you need to take on to be successful in UX design (although you will gain some appreciation of it through the learning process).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a great into to UX then this course by David Travis is worth investigating. https://www.udemy.com/ultimate-guide-to-ux/learn/v4/overview
He also runs an active Facebook page for students. I don't know about the coursera one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a reading list. the following titles have been extremely helpful to me:

**About Face:**

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/About-Face-Essentials-Interaction-Design/dp/1118766571](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118766571)

**Don't make me Think:**

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Dont-Make-Think-Revisited-Usability/dp/0321965515/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1463733758&sr=1-1&keywords=dont+make+me+think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321965515)

**The Design Of Everyday Things:**

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Design-Everyday-Things-Revised-Expanded/dp/0465050654/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1463733779&sr=1-1&keywords=design+of+everyday+things](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465050654)